# How to make gnuplot give you the coefficients of a data fit

Tags: plot, gnuplot, data-fitting

I'm using gnuplot to fit data to a certain function with unknown coefficients. I can get gnuplot to plot the fitted function, but I can't figure out how to have gnuplot give me the actual equation of that function.

The main command is:

```
f(x) = a/(1+(b*(x-c)*(x-c)))
a=80
b=.001
c=70
fit f(x) "data.dat" using 1:2:3 via a,b,c
```

I want gnuplot to tell me the values it comes up with for a b and c. Or maybe I am misinterpreting this command and it is actually using the values I plugged in as a,b, and c. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

After fitting the values are stored in the respective variables `a`, `b` and `c`

```
f(x) = a/(1+(b*(x-c)*(x-c)))
a=80
b=.001
c=70
fit f(x) "data.dat" using 1:2:3 via a,b,c

print a, b, c

plot "data.dat" w p, f(x) title sprintf("a=%e, b=%e, c=%e", a, b, c)
```